# Reuse activity from two activities, via startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities (ACT1 and ACT2), and both are calling another activity (ACT3) using startActivityForResult(intent, 0). I't very strange because ACT1 receives correctly the result in his method onActivityResult, but ACT2 does not. Simply onActivityResult is not triggered in this case. ¿There is a reason for it, or it's a bug?

Thanks in advance!

p.s: added code

---

```
public class ACT1 extends Activity
{
  .........


  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
  {
    ..........

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ACT3.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d(TAG, "ACT1: onActivityResult");

    this.finish();
  }
}
```

---

```
public class ACT2 extends Activity
{
.........


  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
  {
    ..........

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ACT3.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
  } 

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d(TAG, "ACT2: onActivityResult");

    this.finish();
  } 
}
```

---

```
public class ACT3 extends Activity
{
.......


  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.phaBtnAceptar:
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("alarmTime", alarmTime);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

            finish();

            break;

        ........
    }
  }
}
```

---

here the method that sets the alarm, that calls ACT2 (AlarmaListaActivity)

```
private static void asignarAlarma(Context ctx, String idLista, String nombreLista, long horaInicioAlarma)
{
    String idAlarma = DAOMarket.getInstance().insertarAlarma(idLista, nombreLista, "" + horaInicioAlarma, "0");

    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ACT2.class);
    intent.putExtra("idLista", idLista);
    intent.putExtra("nombreLista", nombreLista);
    intent.putExtra("horaInicioAlarma", horaInicioAlarma);

    PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, Integer.parseInt(idAlarma), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, horaInicioAlarma, mAlarmSender);
}
```

Comment: Need to see some code. After Act3 has finished to you call finish() before trying to start it again from act2?

Comment: Be more clear what "not correctly" means. Post the relevant code - you may edit your question for this purpose.

Comment: is ACT1 gets called in place of calling ACT2 ie. is ACT1 running in background are some thing similar to it?

Comment: I added the code to a better explanation of the problem

Comment: The problem is tha ACT1 shows the line "ACT1: onActivityResult", so this method executes, but "ACT2: onActivityResult" is never  shown.

Comment: an important detail is that ACT2 (the activity not calling onActvityResult) is called from AlarmManager, so it comes from a PendingIntent.

Comment: addet the method that sets the alarm, that calls ACT2

Comment: Try to trace through using the debugger in Eclipse or whatever IDE you're using. Confirm that each step you expect to run is running and/or is returning the value you expect. This will allow you to identify the exact place that it goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, the problem was that in androidmanifest.xml I defined act2 as "nohistory", when I taked off this configuration all seems to work fine!
Thanks again and regards!

Answer (score 0):

in act3, try changing

```
intent = new Intent();
```

with

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```